# Empty string becomes null when passed from Delphi to C# as a function argument

Tags: c#, delphi, com-interop

I have a native Delphi exe which calls into C# dll via COM interop. Here's the simplest case which demonstrate this issue:

Delphi:

```
IClass1 = interface(IDispatch)
  ['{B29BAF13-E9E4-33D7-9C92-FE28416C662D}']
  function Test(const aStr: WideString): WideString; safecall;
end;

var
  obj: IClass1;
  s: string;
begin
  obj := CoClass1.Create as IClass1;
  s := obj.Test('');  // Returns '[null]'
end;
```

C#:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IClass1
{
    string Test(string aStr);
}

[ComVisible(true)]
public class Class1 : IClass1
{
    public string Test(string aStr)
    {
        if (aStr == null) return "[null]";
        if (aStr == "") return "[empty]";
        return "Not empty: " + aStr;
    }
}
```

When I call method Test with an empty string in Delphi, the C# part receives null as a parameter value. Why is that? Shouldn't it be an empty string also?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Delphi, `AnsiString`, `UnicodeString`, and `WideString` values are represented by a `nil` pointer when they are empty.  COM uses `BSTR` for strings. Delphi wraps `BSTR` with `WideString`.  So there is no way to pass an "empty" non-nil string to a COM method that takes a `WideString` as a parameter, it will be `nil` instead.

Comment: Yes, but you are not forced to use WideString, as I point out in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Delphi, a null (i.e., `nil`) and empty string are treated as equivalent. As such, passing `''` for a string (or `WideString`) parameter passes `nil` internally -

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

procedure Foo(const S: WideString);
begin
  WriteLn(Pointer(S) = nil);
end;

begin
  Foo('Something');  //FALSE
  Foo('');  //TRUE
  ReadLn;
end.
```

The equation of null and empty strings was in fact copied from COM... so a COM library isn't really the place to insist on a C#-style distinction between the two.

Comment: COM does make a distinction. A `BSTR` can be NULL or a 0-length non-NULL.  It is Delphi that does not make a distinction.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - for sure it can technically be given many COM conventions do not get compiler support in (say) C++. However, code is (or at least was) supposed to treat a null and zero-length `BSTR` as equivalent (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/12/52976.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Why does passing `''` to a `WideString` parameter result in the other side receiving `null`? Well, that's just how Delphi represents an empty COM `BSTR`. If you really need to pass an empty string, you need to change `IClass1` in the Delphi code to pass `TBStr` instead of `WideString` and use `SysAllocString` or `SysAllocStringLen` to create an empty `TBStr`.

Change the declaration of the function in the Delphi code to:

```
function Test(const aStr: TBStr): WideString; safecall;
```

And pass `SysAllocStringLen('', 0)` when you need to pass an empty string.

Here is a complete demonstration:

**C#**

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public interface IClass1
    {
        string Test(string aStr);
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class Class1 : IClass1
    {
        public string Test(string aStr)
        {
            if (aStr == null) return "[null]";
            if (aStr == "") return "[empty]";
            return "Not empty: " + aStr;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"Project1.dll")]
        static extern void Foo(IClass1 intf);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IClass1 intf = new Class1();
            Foo(intf);
        }
    }
}
```

**Delphi**

```
uses
  Ole2;

type
  IClass1 = interface(System.IDispatch)
    function Test(const aStr: TBStr): WideString; safecall;
  end;

var
  EmptyBStr: TBStr;

procedure Foo(const intf: IClass1); stdcall;
begin
  Writeln(intf.Test(nil));
  Writeln(intf.Test(EmptyBStr));
  Writeln(intf.Test(SysAllocString('foo')));
end;

exports
  Foo;

begin
  EmptyBStr := SysAllocStringLen('', 0);
end.
```

**Output**

```
[null]
[empty]
Not empty: foo
```

Comment: I have updated my question with interface declaration. I didn't add it in the first place, because it was auto generated from the type library.

Comment: @Max Thanks. My latest update shows you how to pass an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid errors by null pointers you can send an empty character with Chr (#0) or AnsiChar(#0) instead of '' that returns a null.